# "Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action" windows XP, outlook 2007, connect to exchange using HTTP

Tags: windows-xp, email, exchange, outlook

I can't connect to an exchange server using windows XP and outlook 2007, using the "connect anywhere over HTTP" process, it has been working until recently and the user reports no recent changes to his environment.

The error is "Outlook must be online or connected to complete this action"
It will prompt me for the username and password which I can enter, then it will give the errorm however this only happens when I delete the account and enter all details for the excahnge server again.

The client computer that is unable to connect using outlook can connect to the HTTPS mail service and login send/receive fine. 
Nobody else has reported issues. 
making a test environment with a clean install of XP and outlook 2007 gives the same error, but using windows 7 and outlook 2007 connects perfectly fine everytime.

I also removed all passwords using control keymgr.dll which didnt help. 
Any assistance or ideas would be appreciated, at this point nothing I've tried from technet or google works <_<

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by deleting the .ost file.

Comment: so, it was a local profile issue.. was going to suggest creating a new one.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.